# How to pass specific value to a cell when that cell is selected?

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue, didselectrowatindexpath, indexpath

In short how to call performforsegue method inside didselect row for indexpath. I have an array and this array is the contents of tableView

```
`let array = ["USD","Inr", "AUD", "AED"]`
```

and I have values for this array

```
let valueUSD = "65"
let valueInr = "10"
let valueAUD = "70"
let valueAED = "20"
```

I have another viewController with an optional string and a label and on the viewdidload I called

```
label.text = optionalstring //just a pseudocode but you get the idea
```

Now comes the problem, when the user selects USD I want the optionalstring to take the value of valueUSD variable and when he selects INR it should take valueInr variables value so on , so that the destination view controller will display this value, I don't know how to achieve this, how to gethold of selected indexpath.row and based on that how to set the value, for example

```
if indexpath.row == 0

`destinationViewController.optionalString = valueUSD`
```

I appreciate your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store your data in an array of your custom struct type:

```
let array = [
    MyData(name: "USD", number: "65"),
    MyData(name: "Inr", number: "10"),
    MyData(name: "AUD", number: "70"),
    MyData(name: "AED", number: "20"),
]
```

where `MyData` is like this:

```
struct MyData { // please give this a better name based on the data that you are working with!
    let name: String
    let number: String
}
```

You'd probably need to change your `cellForRowAt` method to set the cell's label text to `array[indexPath.row].name` rather than `array[indexPath.row]`.

In `didSelectRowAt`:

```
let selectedData = array[indexPath.row].number
performSegue(withIdentifier: "insert your segue identifier here", sender: selectedData)
```

And then, override `prepare(for:sender:)`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? TypeOfTheDestinationVC,
        let number = sender as? String {
        vc.optionalString = number
    }
}
```